# Write "currdate" as HTML content for span.fecha

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `<span class="fecha"></span>` and then have this in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currdate = moment().format("DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss A");
    $(".fecha").html(currdate);
});
```

But nothing is printed. What

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6MZ2M/

Comment: Step one, make sure you've included the jQuery library. Step 2 check the console for errors. That will give you more info on what's gone wrong, because as it stands your code is fine.

Comment: @JonP all is fine and no JS errors comes in the console, that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have an error somewhere else, because that code works:

```
<span class="fecha"></span>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var currdate = moment().format("DD MMMM YYYY hh:mm:ss A");
    $(".fecha").html(currdate);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6hA2/